# jqgrid submit button not working

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, jqgrid

This is probably something so obvious, but I can't get the Submit button to post the changes in my jqgrid.  I tried putting the table inside a form field thinking that would help.  The Cancel button works.  Any ideas are appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {

    jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid({
        url:'cfc/jqgrid.cfc?method=jsonContacts&returnformat=json&queryformat=struct',
        width:"auto",
        height:"auto",
        datatype: "json",
        colNames:['contactID','lastname', 'Email'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'contactid',index:'contactid', width:55, search: true},
            {name:'lastname',index:'lastname', width:100, search: true, editable:true},
            {name:'email',index:'email', width:250, search: true, editable:true}
        ],
jsonReader : {repeatitems: false, id: "{id}}"},         
 rowNum:10,rownumbers:true,
rowList:[10,20,30],
sortname: 'contactid',
viewrecords: true,
recordtext: "Record {0} - {1} of {2}",//Pager information to show
sortorder: "desc",
editurl:"cfc/jqgrid.cfc?method=editContact&returnformat=json&queryformat=struct", //The Add/Edit function call 
caption:"Contact List",
pager: '#pager'
        });

jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false});

jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{searchOnEnter:false});

jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pager', 
    {   edit: true, 
        editicon: "ui-icon-pencil", 
        add: true, 
        addicon: "ui-icon-plus", 
        save:true, 
        saveicon: "ui-icon-disk", 
        cancel: true, 
        cancelicon: "ui-icon-cancel"}
        );

     });

</script>

<form method="post">
<table id="editgrid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div><br>
<input type="BUTTON" id="editgrid" value="Edit Selected" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If your latest update is correct then you have two objects with the same `id` "editgrid".  You cant do that.  They must be unique.

Comment: You can remove `<form method="post">` and `<input type="BUTTON" id="editgrid" value="Edit Selected" /></form>` which are not needed for jqGrid. You should use more recent version of jQuery. jqGrid 4.6 support starting with 1.7.x, but I recommend you to use jQuery 1.11.2 or jQuery 1.10.2. I recommend you to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox to trace HTTP traffic and to verify whether the editing results do be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all of your help.  I didn't realize I had responses.  I'm not sure how to get email notifications.

It was the version of jquery.  Once I changed it to 1.11.2, it worked.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

I also removed:

```
jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pager', 
{   edit: true, 
    editicon: "ui-icon-pencil", 
    add: true, 
    addicon: "ui-icon-plus", 
    save:true, 
    saveicon: "ui-icon-disk", 
    cancel: true, 
    cancelicon: "ui-icon-cancel"}
    );
```

One thing that is happening now is that only some of the columns populate with data.  I'm not sure why some do and some do not.  The edit feature will modify all the rows/columns in the database, but it will not display some of the data even though it is in the database.  Some of the columns do display and refresh properly with updated data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in your HTML and it should look like this

```
<form method="post">
<table id="editgrid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div><br>
<input type="submit" id="bedata" value="Edit Selected" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I changed input type to submit, and it still doesn't work.  I'm wondering if I don't have all of the scripts that I need.

Comment: I'm not able to get it to work without the inlineNav and navGrid edit:true, either.